# Global variable sencha touch 2.1

Tags: global-variables, sencha-touch-2.1

Hi I need to define a global variable to use in anywhere of my application.
I declare a global variable **baseUrl** in my **app.js**. Please see below
app.js

```
    //<debug>
Ext.Loader.setPath({
    'Ext': 'touch/src',//Location of the sencha touch source files
    'bluebutton': 'app',



});
//</debug>



Ext.application({
    name: 'bluebutton',//Application Path, all classes in you app. For eg blueButton.view.Main.case sensitive

    views: ['Main',

    'BlueButton.CouponMain',
    'BlueButton.CouponList',
    'BlueButton.CouponList2',
    'BlueButton.CouponList3',

    'BlueButton.TransactionMain',


    ],



   stores : [
   'BlueButton.GlobalVariable',


   ], 

    models : ['BlueButton.GlobalVariable',
    'BlueButton.MemberDetail',


     ],



    controllers: ['Main', 
    'BlueButton.MemberList', 


    ],



    requires: [
        'Ext.MessageBox',

    ],

    icon: {
        '57': 'resources/icons/Icon.png',
        '72': 'resources/icons/Icon~ipad.png',
        '114': 'resources/icons/Icon@2x.png',
        '144': 'resources/icons/Icon~ipad@2x.png'
    },

    isIconPrecomposed: true,

    startupImage: {
        '320x460': 'resources/startup/320x460.jpg',
        '640x920': 'resources/startup/640x920.png',
        '768x1004': 'resources/startup/768x1004.png',
        '748x1024': 'resources/startup/748x1024.png',
        '1536x2008': 'resources/startup/1536x2008.png',
        '1496x2048': 'resources/startup/1496x2048.png'
    },


    //--Global value--
    baseUrl: 'http://192.168.251.108:8080',
    //--Global value--



    launch: function() {

        // Destroy the #appLoadingIndicator element
        Ext.fly('appLoadingIndicator').destroy();


        // Initialize the main view

             var LoginLS = Ext.getStore('LoginLS');
             LoginLS.load();

             var record =  LoginLS.getAt(0);



            if(record != undefined){
                var sessionId = record.get('sessionId');
               if (sessionId !=undefined){
                        var mainView = Ext.getCmp("mainview");
                        if(!mainView){
                        mainView = Ext.create('bluebutton.view.Main');
                        }

                        Ext.Viewport.setActiveItem(mainView);  
               }
               else
               {
                        var loginView = Ext.getCmp("loginview");
                        if(!loginView){
                        loginView = Ext.create('bluebutton.view.Login');
                        }

                        Ext.Viewport.setActiveItem(loginView); 
                }
            }
            else{
                      var loginView = Ext.getCmp("loginview");
                        if(!loginView){
                        loginView = Ext.create('bluebutton.view.Login');
                        }

                        Ext.Viewport.setActiveItem(loginView); 



//                        //--Disable this line --
//                          var mainView = Ext.getCmp("mainview");
//                        if(!mainView){
//                        mainView = Ext.create('bluebutton.view.Main');
//                        }

//                        Ext.Viewport.setActiveItem(mainView);  
//                         //--Disable this line --





               }




//        Ext.create('bluebutton.view.TopMenuList');

    },

     init: function () {
        this.callParent(arguments);

    },


    onUpdated: function() {
        Ext.Msg.confirm(
            "Application Update",
            "This application has just successfully been updated to the latest version. Reload now?",
            function(buttonId) {
                if (buttonId === 'yes') {
                    window.location.reload();
                }
            }
        );
    }
});
```

model.js

```
Ext.define('bluebutton.model.BlueButton.CouponList', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    config: {
        idProperty: 'couponId',
        fields: [
            {  name: 'couponId'  },
            {  name: 'couponName'  },
            {  name: 'description'  },
            {  name: 'amount'  },
            {  name: 'couponType'  },

            {  name: 'merchant_bbID'  },
            {  name: 'sessionId'  },
            {  name: 'deviceId'  },



        ],

        proxy: {
            type: 'rest',
            url: bluebutton.app.baseUrl +'/WebCommon/rest/BBWebService/getCouponList',


            actionMethods: {
                create: 'POST',
                read: 'GET',
                update: 'PUT',
                destroy: 'DELETE'
            },


                      noCache: false, // get rid of the '_dc' url parameter

                    extraParams: {
                    sessionId: "1",
                      merchant_bbID: "merchant1",

                },


//            timeout:1000,
//            listeners: {
//                exception: function(proxy, response, operation) {
//                     alert("Connection Problem");
//                       Ext.Viewport.setMasked(false); // hide the load screen
//                       
//                  }
//               },

            reader: {
                type: 'json',
                 rootProperty: 'couponList'

            },

            writer: {
                type: 'json',

            },
        }



    }

});
```

Then I used basedUrl in my model.js. 
It can work when I use browser to view. But when I use **sencha app build testing** to compile my apps,

I used browser to open and it showed me an error message **Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'baseUrl' of undefined** . Any idea?

Comment: Did the below answer help?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

When you make the production build, all the files in your sencha app will be minified and thus the global variables may lose the context.

There are several ways to declare global variables in your sencha app

-> 1st Approach

Declare a global variables in util/Config.js

**util/Config.js**

```
Ext.define('APP.util.Config', { 
    singleton : true,
    alias : 'widget.appConfigUtil',
        config : {
        baseUrl : 'xx.xx.xx.xxx',
    },
    constructor: function(config) {
        this.initConfig(config);
        this.callParent([config]);
    }
})
```

Changes in **app.js**

```
requires : [ 'App.util.Config']
```

Now, you can use it in your application like as below.

```
var baseUrl = App.util.Config.getBaseUrl();
```

---

2nd Approach->

Declare global variables in your .js files before the class definition

```
var baseUrl;

Ext.define('classname,{Other things });
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple example

In your app.js add the variables. To test you variables type app.app.VariableName within your google chrome console. Chrome will autocomplete for you.

```
Ext.application({
    name: 'app',

    /** 
     * Custom Variables
     * Use app.app.baseUrl to access the value
     */
    baseUrl : 'http://example.com',
    variable01 : 'foo',
    variable02 : 'bar',

    ...

});
```

Comment: This approach doesn't work for global vars in which you wanna use in `config` property in models or stores